# Upgrade Cordova Framework from 2.0.0 to 2.5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I want to upgrade the Cordova framework in my iOS project by following this [tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html).

The current version is 2.0.0, and I download the newest version 2.5.0 from [website](http://cordova.apache.org/).

However, the tutorial seems pretty complicated. I am wondering if there is a way to upgrade Cordova framework directly from 2.0.0 to 2.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to upgrade from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 then 2.2.0 .... 2.5.0

just follow the instructions

-- OR --

create a new project with phonegap 2.5.0 and copy your files, plugins and edit the config file to match the previous project

Comment: How can I upgrade Cordova from 2.4.0 to 2.5.0?

Comment: follow these instructions: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides